# Is it possible to import fonts from the directory with scss?

Tags: sass

I have a scss file with font import implemented this way:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Caption:400,700&subset=latin-ext,cyrillic);
```

I understand that using CDN gives advantages in caching for user but this is internal site and it could be used on server without access to the `wide web`. And I'm not sure that user machine will have access to the Internet too. So I want to serve fronts with other pages static files.

Is there a way in SCSS to import fonts from the some directory on server? Something like:

```
@import dir(/path/to/fonts/file)
```

Or SCSS has not this feature?

Comment: add @font-face directly to the sass file

Answer (score 94, accepted):

As far as I know you can't import fonts using `@import` in SCSS. You can include fonts using `@font-face`. For example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url(path/to/file) format(Example: 'truetype' or 'opentype' depending on the file extension of your font);
}


// USAGE
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: This is what the `@import` from google fonts does. If you put the import url into your browser this is what you see (a bunch of `@font-face`'s).

Comment: Works great. It is now also recommended to add `font-display: swap;` in the `@font-face` rule. Gives you some extra Google points ;) See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display

Comment: How can I get multiple boldness sizes?

Answer (score 5):

it's a bit late but you can use the following format with libsass for external imports

`@import url("http...");`

Comment: I don't think the url should have any quotes around it

Comment: is there corresponding @use usage?
`@use url("http...");` and `@use "http...";` don't seem to work

Answer (score 4):

Usually it's used to import CSS fragments or files and not fonts.
Try this workaround if you are using Ruby SASS/SCSS and try without brackets.

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Caption:400,700&subset=latin-ext,cyrillic.css";
```

I put a `.css` behind it. Works for me with Ruby SASS/SCSS but not with LibSass though.

Answer (score 1):

import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';

In the constructor of your web part you can load it using the SPComponentLoader

```
export default class WebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<WebPartProps> {
    constructor() {
      super();
    
      SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in angular you can add a dependency on the package.json

```
"@fontsource/nunito-sans": "^4.5.1",
"@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.7",
```

Then you can add this on the scss file as import.

```
@import "@fontsource/nunito-sans";
@import "@fontsource/roboto";
```

And then use then on the styles

```
$fontFamily: "Nunito Sans", "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans+Caption&display=swap');
```

use font-family like

```
font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Link to an external resource:

```
@font-face {
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/your-font')
  ...
}
```

Link to a relative file (did not work for me):

```
@font-face {
  src: url('../../assets/fonts/your-font-name.woff2')
  ...
}
```

*I had an issue when using relative path which appears to be a [SCSS Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5213)*

So I used the absolute path and it worked:

```
@font-face {
  src: url('/root-dir/assets/fonts/your-font-name.woff2')
  ...
}
```